# Error in subquery in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table, `customers_categorization`:

```
customer__id    visit_month    cust_type
2170809793      0              lagger
2170809793      10             retained
2170809793      11             retained
2170809793      12             lagger
2170809793      17             lagger
2170809793      23             retained
2170809793      24             lost
2174188545      0              lost
```

I am trying to write a SQL query in Postgresql where I want to find the proportion of customers who returned by month:

Here is what I have so far:

```
select visit_month,
       count(select customer__id from customers_categorization where cust_type=’retained’)/count(customer__id) as retention_rate
    from customers_categorization
    group by 1;
```

I keep getting a "syntax error at or near "select". I am not sure why this isn't working. Does postgresql not accept subqueries with the select statement?

Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the syntax of `count()` with `filter`:

```
select
    visit_month,
    count(customer__id) filter (where cust_type = 'retained') /
        count(customer__id) as retention_rate
from customers_categorization
group by 1;
```

or with `case`:

```
select
    visit_month,
    count(case when cust_type = 'retained' then customer__id end) /
        count(customer__id) as retention_rate
from customers_categorization
group by 1;
```